# Files uploaded via Google Drive api v3 are created on user drive instead of shard drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am uploading a file to a our company's shared drive using google drive api v3.
The file is uploaded but to my user's drive instead of the company's shared drive.

I am using a "multipart" upload type
Any idea what is wrong?

This is the code I have:

```
String body = delimiter + 
     'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n' + 
     '{' +
       '"name" : "' + params[0].filename + '",' + 
       '"description" : "' + params[0].fileDescription + '",' +
       '"driveId" : "' + params[0].**driveId** + '",' + 
       '"mimeType" : "' + mimeType + '",' + 
       '"parents": [{"id":"'+ params[0].**FolderId** +'"}]' +
     '}' + 
      delimiter + 
      'Content-Type: ' + mimeType +
      '\r\n' + 
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' + '\r\n' + 
      bodyEncoded + close_delim;
```

This is the full callout:

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
req1.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&supportsAllDrives=true');
req1.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accesstoken);
req1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/related; boundary="' + boundary + '"');
req1.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(body.length()));
req1.setBody(body);
req1.setMethod('POST');
req1.setTimeout(60 * 1000);
HttpResponse resp1 = http.send(req1);
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the request?

Comment: did you do a drive.list to get the drive id?

Comment: @DaImTo yes, I see the drive, same ID I am using

Comment: @Jescanellas added the callout code but as I wrote the file is being created, its only the placement of the file which is not working

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Might be a stupid question, but do you have edit permissions for that Shared Drive? Do you have another Shared Drive to test with?

Comment: @Jescanellas the user who we used to authenticate the app is set as manager for the drive.I would expect to get an error if there is a permission issue but instead I am getting success and the file is located at this user's own drive

Comment: I'm out of ideas here. I recommend you to contact [G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) since it looks an specific issue with that Drive.